# No Gradient in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, bayesian

I wrote some code to do variational inference on a markov random field in tensorflow.  But it's not quite working, as the gradient doesn't exist or something so it doesn't update the parameters and would appreciate help.  My code is here:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import math as m

samples = 10
#create data

x_matrix = np.random.randn(5,100)

#priors are 5 gaussians with mean 0 and stdev 1



#construct variational family
rv = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [samples,5])
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = [5, 100])


p_mean = tf.Variable(np.random.randn(1,5).astype(np.float32))
p_stdev = tf.Variable(np.random.lognormal(size = (1,5)).astype(np.float32))
W = tf.multiply(tf.tile(p_stdev,[samples,1]),rv) + tf.tile(p_mean,[samples,1])

#construct the computational graph

b = tf.Variable(np.random.randn())
likelihood = tf.exp(tf.matmul(W,X) + b)
posterior = tf.add(tf.log(likelihood),tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.log((tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.exp(-0.5*(x)**2) / ((2*m.pi)**0.5), W))),1),[10,1]))
tot_posterior_like = tf.reduce_sum(posterior, 1)
#variational family likelihood
q_like = tf.reduce_sum(tf.log((tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.exp(-0.5*(x)**2) / ((2*m.pi)**0.5), rv))),1)

#partition function estimate
Zest = tf.reduce_mean(tot_posterior_like - q_like)

loss = tf.reduce_mean(q_like - tot_posterior_like + Zest)

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(.01)
minimize1 = optimizer.minimize(loss)
grads = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()

sess.run(init_op)

flag = True


for each in range(3):

    if flag:
        rvinput = np.random.randn(samples,5)
        sess.run(minimize1, {rv : rvinput, X : x_matrix})
        print(sess.run(p_mean))
        print(sess.run(p_stdev))
        print(sess.run(b))
        print(sess.run(loss, {rv : rvinput, X : x_matrix}))
        print(each)
        for gv in grads:
            print(str(sess.run(gv[0])))

print(sess.run(p_mean))
print(sess.run(p_stdev))
print(sess.run(b))
sess.close()
```

When I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-15e721d2dae0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/cameron/Downloads/Estimating_ERGM.py', wdir='/home/cameron/Downloads')

  File "/home/cameron/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 866, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/cameron/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/cameron/Downloads/Estimating_ERGM.py", line 72, in <module>
    print(str(sess.run(gv[0])))

  File "/home/cameron/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 778, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/home/cameron/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 969, in _run
    fetch_handler = _FetchHandler(self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_string)

  File "/home/cameron/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 408, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)

  File "/home/cameron/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 227, in for_fetch
    (fetch, type(fetch)))

TypeError: Fetch argument None has invalid type <class 'NoneType'>
```

The error doesn't bother me honestly but I think it is symptomatic of the code not computing any gradients.  When I run the code without trying to print the gradient, the code runs but it doesn't update the parameters, ie The parameters/weights don't change at each iteration.  This is really what I need fixed as I want to build a model that updates.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the culprit is the flow of execution:

Here is your current flow:

```
if flag:
        rvinput = np.random.randn(samples,5)
        sess.run(minimize1, {rv : rvinput, X : x_matrix})
       #rest doesn't matter
```

If you just run the gradient alone then the loss isn't run.

Try this instead

```
if flag:
        rvinput = np.random.randn(samples,5)
        loss, _ = sess.run([loss, minimize1], feed_dict = {rv : rvinput, X : x_matrix})
```

Comment: Hey I thought this solved the problem but it didn't.  I think the problem is with Zest when I take it out the gradients resolve but with it in there is problems.  The way I set this problem up, there is an chance (but I didn't think through the math) that Zest makes all the gradients cancel out, however I tried to do `tf.NotDifferentiable("Zest")` but that didn't help either.